# No node found for selector when id contains $

Tags: puppeteer

the id of the selector contains $ and / and it will not able to get the element, can anyone help on this

below is the html code, i am trying to get the element

```
<ul id="/job$Menu" class="ant-menu  ant-menu-sub ant-menu-inline" role="menu"><li class="ant-menu-item" role="menuitem" style="padding-left: 48px;"><a href="/job/create"><span>Create Job</span></a></li><li class="ant-menu-item" role="menuitem" style="padding-left: 48px;"><a href="/job/list"><span>Jobs</span></a></li></ul>
```

the selector get from devtools is

```
#\/job\$Menu > li:nth-child(1) > a
```

i use below code to get the element in puppeteer

```
page.click('#\\/test\\$Menu > li:nth-child(1) > a');
```

buy always get below error:

```
(node:63727) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: No node found for selector: #\/job\$Menu > li:nth-child(1) > a
```

hope to get element `<a href="/job/create">`

Comment: I have a question, why it says /job and then /test on the selector?

Comment: What about `[href="/job/create"]`?

Comment: sorry it's a typo. both should be /job.
and i tried [href="/job/create"] and it's not work
(node:66961) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: No node found for selector: [href="/job/create"]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two possible errors that could be popping up here.

1. You got the selector format wrong. 
   To confirm/deny that this is true, you'll have to execute code directly in your browser. Click inspect element -> console and enter the following line.

`$('#\\/test\\$Menu > li:nth-child(1) > a')`

You should be able to see elements there to confirm your selector is correct.

2. The selector isn't visible. Run the following code to have your puppeteer wait for the selector to become visible.

`page.waitForSelector('#\\/test\\$Menu > li:nth-child(1) > a',{visible: true})`

Good luck! Let me know how it goes.

Comment: i can get the element in browser console by document.querySelector('#\\/job\\$Menu > li:nth-child(1) > a'), and it will return
<a href=​"/​job/​create">​…​</a>​

Comment: the 2nd point you mentioned is the real cause, when i run the waitforselector method and then invoke the click method again, it works. really appreciate for your prompt answer and help.

Comment: await page.waitForSelector('#\\/job\\$Menu > li:nth-child(1) > a',{visible: true});
 page.click('#\\/job\\$Menu > li:nth-child(1) > a');

Answer (score 0):

how about this

```
    let elements = await page.$$('li.ant-menu-item');
    for (let i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        let  a_el  =  await elements[i].$('a');
        let  a_el_href = await page.evaluate(el => el.getAttribute('href'),a_el);
        if(a_el_href == '/job/create')
        {
            a_el.click();
        }
    }
```

Comment: thanks for this answer, i tried this way and it still not work